# HTML2PDF not working in live in yii

Tags: php, yii, html2pdf

i used HTML2PDF in my site which is developed in YII framework. it is working fine our server. When I moved those codes in client server it won't works. the page took long time for loading and finally display as timeout error.

I checked with fwrite function that also works fine. but PDF won't. what is the issue?.

```
$fp = fopen('media/files/test1.txt', 'w');
        fwrite($fp, 'BINGO COUPON');
        fwrite($fp, '123456789');
        fclose($fp);
```

test1.file is created successfully in the specified path.

```
$pdffile = 'media/files/bingo_rr.pdf';

try
    {   
                    $html2pdf = Yii::app()->ePdf->HTML2PDF('L', 'A4', 'en', true, 'UTF-8', 0);      
            $html2pdf->pdf->IncludeJS("print(true);");
            $html2pdf->WriteHTML($this->renderPartial('printcouponpdf', array( 'couponlist' => @$couponlist, 'coupon_details' => $coupon_model_details), true));
            $html2pdf->Output($pdffile, 'F');
    }    
                        catch(HTML2PDF_exception $e) {
        echo $e;
        exit;
    }
```

html2pdf library included in main.php

```
'ePdf' => array(
        'class'         => 'ext.yii-pdf.EYiiPdf',
        'params'        => array(              
            'HTML2PDF' => array(
                'librarySourcePath' => 'application.vendor.html2pdf.*',
                'classFile'         => 'html2pdf.class.php', // For adding to Yii::$classMap                
            )
        ),
    )
```

but PDF file does not created.

Comment: @martincho but text file created in the same path. why PDF not created?.

Comment: Do you have images in your pdf? I believe I had issues with this in the past. I had to use absolute paths to the images to get it to work.

Comment: @Pitchinnate yes i have background image and color also. i gave as absolute paths only. but it does not works

Comment: Do you know how to run a test php from command line? I'm assuming you're using Linux. The problem is when you execute it from console, you can SUDO, and if it works it means you have a problem with your web server user and permission.

Comment: @martincho no i am using windows machine only. i don't know  how to run a test php from command line. could you help me?.

Comment: i had great fun trying to get HTML2PDF to work with images in a yii application. in the end, using the *full image url* in the html template is what worked for me. you say you're using absolute paths - is that absolute web path or filesystem path - coz that might be the problem. either way, you could try taking the images out altogether and see if it's possible to generate a text-only pdf.